# Integer Solutions to $\sqrt{1+2cx_1}+\sqrt{1+2cx_2}=c$ where $c$ is constant integer?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

The following equation has infinite  number of solutions in real numbers and information is not enough to solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1+2cx_1}+\sqrt{1+2cx_2}=c\quad(1)\end{align*}$$

I am wondering that if we assume all variables can only take integer values that is $x_1,x_2,c\in\mathbb{N}$ will there be a way to first check if there is a solution and if yes how to find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

As an example I have taken the case where $c=42$:
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1+84x_1}+\sqrt{1+84x_2}=42\quad(2)\end{align*}$$

Checking all possible integer values I could find that $x_1=2, x_2=10$ is a solution.

So far as a clue I think I need to use the sequence of perfect square numbers but I don't know how. Please guide me if you know the solution or a way that might result in the solution. Algorithmic methods are just fine as well.

Comment: $(0,20)$ is also a solution for $c=42$. Are you excluding $0$ ?

Comment: Both the square roots must individually be while numbers, and searching for when $1+2xc=(2k+1)^2$ for some k is easier than checking all x.

Comment: It's hard to prove this, but I can confirm that both square root terms must be whole numbers (someone used algebraic geometry to show it).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1} + \sqrt{1+2cx_2} &= c \\
   (\sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2})(\sqrt{1+2cx_1} + \sqrt{1+2cx_2}) 
      &= (\sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2})c \\
   (1+2cx_1) - (1+2cx_2) &= (\sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2})c \\
   (\sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2})c &= 2c(x_1 - x_2) \\
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2} &= 2(x_1 - x_2) \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1} + \sqrt{1+2cx_2} &= c \\
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1} - \sqrt{1+2cx_2} &= 2(x_1 - x_2) \\
\hline
   2\sqrt{1+2cx_1} &= 2(x_1-x_2)+c \\
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1} &= (x_1-x_2)+ \dfrac c2 \\
   1+2cx_1 &= (x_1-x_2)^2 + (x_1-x_2)c + \dfrac{c^2}{4} \\
\hline
   2\sqrt{1+2cx_2} &=  c - 2(x_1-x_2) \\
   \sqrt{1+2cx_2} &=  \dfrac c2 - (x_1-x_2) \\
   1+2cx_2 &= (x_1-x_2)^2 - (x_1-x_2)c + \dfrac{c^2}{4} \\
\hline
   2c(x_1 + x_2) + 2 &= 2(x_1-x_2)^2 + \dfrac{c^2}{2} \\
   4c(x_1 + x_2) + 4 &= 4(x_1-x_2)^2 + c^2 \\ 
   c^2  - 4(x_1 + x_2)c + (4(x_1-x_2)^2 - 4) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
   c &= 
     \dfrac{4(x_1+x_2) \pm \sqrt{16(x_1+x_2)^2-16(x_1-x_2)^2 + 16}}{2} \\
   c &= \dfrac{4(x_1+x_2) \pm \sqrt{64x_1x_2+16}}{2} \\
   c &= 2(x_1+x_2) \pm 2\sqrt{4x_1x_2+1} \\
\end{align*}

### INTEGER SOLUTIONS?

Lets suppose that $4x_1 x_2 + 1$ is a perfect square. Say, for some integer $N$,
\begin{align}
   4x_1 x_2 + 1 &= (2N+1)^2 \\
   x_1 x_2 &= N(N+1)
\end{align}

Then $c = 2(x_1+x_2) \pm 2\sqrt{4x_1x_2+1} = 2(x_1+x_2) \pm(4N + 2)$.

Assuming $c = 2(x_1+x_2) + 2\sqrt{4x_1x_2+1} = 2(x_1+x_2) + (4N + 2)$, we find

\begin{align}
   \sqrt{1+2cx_1}
   &= \sqrt{1+2[2(x_1+x_2) + (4N + 2)]x_1} \\
   &= \sqrt{4 x_1^2 + 4 x_1 x_2 + 8 x_1 N + 4 x_1 + 1} \\
   &= \sqrt{4 x_1^2 + 4N(N+1) + 8 x_1 N + 4 x_1 + 1} \\
   &= \sqrt{4 x_1^2 + 4 x_1(2N +1) + (2N+1)^2} \\
   &= 2x_1 + (2N+1)
\end{align}

So we must also have  $\sqrt{1+2cx_2} = 2x_2 + (2N+1)$ and we see that

$$\sqrt{1+2cx_1} + \sqrt{1+2cx_2} = c$$

Comment: Something's gone wrong because now $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 10$ isn't a solution of the equation.

Comment: Aha, found it! In the very last line, you should have $±\frac{4\sqrt{4x_1 x_2 + 1}}{2} = ±2\sqrt{4x_1 x_2 + 1}$.

Comment: @Toby Thanks a lot. The older I get the harder it is for be to keep all of my ducks lined up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didn't know I could write the equation explicitly in terms of $c$. Please also give a hint that how do I continue to calculate unknowns?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\sqrt{1+2cx_1}+\sqrt{1+2cx_2}=c\implies c=2 \left(x_1+x_2\pm\sqrt{4 x_1 x_2+1}\right)$$

So, if $(c,x_1,x_2)$ are whole numbers you need that $(4 x_1 x_2+1)$ be the perfect square of an odd integer and $c$ is an even integer.

Comment: very good hint, but I am confused yet.

Answer (score 1):

As Claude showed, we must have c is even. It is a [fact from number theory](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/) that $\sqrt m+ \sqrt n$ cannot be a whole number unless m and n are both perfect squares, and this, together with some modular arithmetic, can aid in the search for solutions. To ease notation slightly, since we know c is even, write c=2d.

Suppose that $1+4xd$ were a perfect square. Since odd perfect squares are congruent to 1 mod 8, we have that xd is even. Suppose $1+4xd=(2k+1)^2$. Then $xd=k(k+1)$. We wish to find possible $k$ which work, which then would let us find x. Rewrite the equation as $k(k+1)\equiv 0 \pmod d$. Now, we apply the Chinese remainder theorem.

Suppose that $q=p^m$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $d$. Reducing our equation mod $q$, and noting that at least one of $k$ and $k+1$ is relatively prime to $q$, we have that the only solutions to $k(k+1)=0 \pmod q$ are $k=0,-1 \pmod q$. The CRT let’s us put those solutions together, and there are algorithmic ways to do so by using the Euclidean algorithm to find modular inverses.

For example, when $c=42, d=21=3\cdot 7$, so we must find numbers that are congruent to either 0 or -1 mod 3 and 7. There are a few combinations we must consider.

If $k=0\pmod 3$ and $k=0\pmod 7$, then $k$ is a multiple of 21. Similarly, if $k=-1$ modulo both 3 and 7, then $k=20 \pmod{21}$

More interesting is when $k=0 \pmod 3, k=-1 \pmod 7$ or vice versa. In the first case, $k=6 \pmod{21}, and in the second, $k=14 \pmod{21}$.

Note that if $d$ has $f$ distinct prime factors, there will be $2^f$ different systems of equations to solve.

Since we must have that $1+4dx\leq (2d)^(2)$ to solve our actual problem,  we must have $k<d$, and so we do not need to consider more than one value of $k$ in each equivalence class. So for our specific purposes, we only consider $k=0, 6, 14, 20$ yield possible $x$ values of $0$, $2$, $10$, and $20$. And, indeed, all 4 of those appear in actual solutions to the problem. The point, however, is that this calculation can be done efficiently by a computer.

Answer (score 1):

We get the parametric solutions $(x_1,x_2)$ of $4x_1x_2+1 = v^2.$

Hence we get $x_2=\large{\frac{(-1+v^2)}{4x_1}}.$

Let $x_1=n$ and $v=2nm \pm 1$, then we get $x_2=m(nm \pm 1).$
n,m are arbitrary integer.

Examples:
$(m,n)=(2,2) \implies (x_1,x_2)=(2, 10),(2, 6)$
$(m,n)=(1,8) \implies (x_1,x_2)=(8, 9),(8, 7)$
$(m,n)=(2,8) \implies (x_1,x_2)=(8, 34),(8, 30)$